# How to add degree symbol in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, html

I have written degree symbol (example: 15°C) in flash but when I export the move the symbol is absconding.
Is there any way to retain the symbol when the movie is rendered?

Comment: Do you use embedded fonts? Did you embed the symbol for °?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the font embedding. Assuming you're using one of the newer Flash (CS3>) you have to go through a really ugly song and dance to get the font embedded.  Click the EMBED button and create an instance of some font you own (give it an obvious name that you can locate... "MY_NEW_FONT" or some such). Check the checkmark next to all the applicable glyphs (keep it to as few as you really think you'll need).  Now, close the dialog and THEN use the font drop down and find the font you just created. It'll have an * next to it and will be near the top.  Now your font is embedded and your asterisk will show.

Comment: That's right! Mark the selected font to be embedded on export.